# How do I find and read from a local file?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to put an API token in a local file so that it isn't displayed in the source code.

```
var apiToken = File('API_TOKEN').readAsStringSync();
```

But this call fails...

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'API_TOKEN' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
#0      _File.throwIfError (dart:io/file_impl.dart:635:7)
#1      _File.openSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:479:5)
#2      _File.readAsBytesSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:539:18)
#3      _File.readAsStringSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:584:18)
#4      apiToken (package:araki/main.dart:17:40)
#5      apiToken (package:araki/main.dart)
#6      main (package:araki/main.dart:21:25)
...
```

API_TOKEN is at the root of my project.  I tried poking around the current working directory and it looked like the root of my hard drive!  I can't keep the file there...

What is the best practice for referring to configuration in local files?

Comment: you first create file as json .when your application create(MAIN METHOD) .then try to read.check exist the file.you can also use sharedpreference instead of file for configuration

Answer (score 1):

On advice, I created a separate class SplitApiConfig.dart

```dart
class SplitApiConfig {
  static const String apiToken = '<my api token here>';
}
```

Then, I imported the file in my main app.

```dart
import 'splitApiToken.dart';
```

I put the file in the same directory as my main.dart

Now I can load the token from an external file...

```dart
final Splitio _split = Splitio(SplitApiConfig.apiToken, 'key', configuration: configurationOptions);
```

By referencing **SplitApiConfig.apiToken**

This did not completely solve my problem.  I wanted to reference an external file with the token that was NOT part of the compile.  Now, if the SplitApiConfig is missing, I will get compilation errors.  Thus the file must stay checked in and I must remember to not have a live API token.

If anybody reading this has a follow-up, I'm still interested in how to find and read from an external file in Flutter.